# Send Followed by Receive on UDP socket

Tags: c++, linux, networking, udp

I have a Client/Server setup on two linux machines connected by a 32 KBps connection. The Client sends 32 byte UDP packets to the Server, and the Server responds with 1024 byte UDP packets. I am running into the following issue...

The Client sends two 32 byte packets to the Server within 2 ms of each other. The Server receives the first packet, and uses the sendto function to respond with the appropriate 1024 byte response packet. It then goes on to call recvfrom, waiting for the second packet from the Client. Given that Sockets are full duplex, I would expect that the recvfrom should complete within at most a few milliseconds, but after repeated tests, it always takes ~32 ms, the time taken to send a 1024 byte packet on a 32 KBps link. Do UDP sockets block receiving until it has sent out all its data? That seems to be what's happening here, but I can find nothing online confirming this.

Comment: You can debug this yourself easily.  Just change your response from 1024 bytes to 65000 bytes.  Does the delay scale accordingly?  Or don't send the response at all.  Does the receiver immediately get both packets?  Better yet, capture the packets in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and analyze them there.

Comment: Do some low level analyse of your data transfer.